Python peewee ORM Error: 'no such table: Tasks'
I'm struggling with peewee in python. My configuration for project is Python + pyTelegramBotAPI + Sqlite3 + peewee. My telegram bot is the task manager (learning project). Here's my code for getting avaliable tasks:
def get_most_recent_tasks(page: int) -> list:
    offset = (3 * page) - 3

    query = TaskModel.select().order_by(TaskModel.creation_date.desc()).limit(3).offset(offset)
    most_recent_tasks = query.execute()
    print(most_recent_tasks)

Here's the error that I get:
most_recent_tasks = query.execute()
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
peewee.OperationalError: no such table: Tasks

Any help appreciated.

Probably you didn't apply a migration to create a Task table. Double check that is indeed in the database.

You may need to create the table if you didn't already. You can write code like:
db.create_tables([TaskModel, ...])

Most likely, though, the problem is that you are specifying a relative path to your database file, e.g.:
db = SqliteDatabase('filename.db')

That path is relative to your current-working directory, and depending on how you run your bot, it may change. Better option is to specify a full/absolute path:
import os
curdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))  # Current dir of module.
db = SqliteDatabase(os.path.join(curdir, 'filename.db'))

